# Could not find configuration package "camera_info_manager" upon build

Tags: ros, rosdep, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner and I am trying to install autoware from this link: https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware I followed the following commands on my virtual machine with ros indigo:

```
cd $HOME
$ git clone https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware.git
$ cd ~/Autoware/ros/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ cd ../..
$ ./catkin_make_release
```

This last command produces the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "camera_info_manager" with any of the following names:

    camera_info_managerConfig.cmake
    camera_info_manager-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "camera_info_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "camera_info_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "camera_info_manager" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264965/could-not-find-configuration-package-%22camera_info_manager%22-upon-build/) by [Cheema](https://answers.ros.org/users/30898/cheema/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the dependency is [already defined](https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware/blob/29a4fc248e28cfbf13e646a25ef2cf06118bd805/ros/src/sensing/drivers/camera/packages/baumer/package.xml#L17). You just have to run [rosdep install to install all dependency in the workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep#Install_dependency_of_all_packages_in_the_workspace) (in fact I opened a [PR](https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware/pull/1116) to add a line to run `rosdep` in the readme).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you might be missing a dependency that needs to be installed before you build. In particular `camera_info_manager` which should be in the kinetic or indigo packages you installed from debian packages. However the instructions don't seem to mention sourcing `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` or the `indigo` version before you try to build which could mean that things are not found.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1